# Cannot get `key` query string parameter to select a specific row

Tags: couchdb

Been banging my head against a wall here. I can't get the `key` query string parameter to select a specific row when querying for documents. Here's a script to run against a fresh database that shows I can query all the documents, but cannot select just one by its key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -ex

# Create a database.
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/names

# Add a few documents.
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"joe"}' http://localhost:5984/names
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"frank"}' http://localhost:5984/names

# Add a view function.
curl \
    -X PUT \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "views": { "by_name": { "map": "function (doc) { if (doc.name) { emit(doc.name, doc.name.toUpperCase()) } }" } } }' \
    http://localhost:5984/names/_design/docs

# Querying all the documents works.
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/names/_design/docs/_view/by_name

# Selecting one of those documents by key does not work.
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/names/_design/docs/_view/by_name?key=frank
```

As far as I can tell I'm following the example in the first paragraph of the ["Find One"](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html#find-one) section of the CouchDB docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key should be JSON-encoded, so use `key="frank"` instead. (just like in the example)

Comment: Darn. I tried that already, but didn't realize I need to escape the quotes on the command line. Thanks!